# Google Places API is removing sublocality_level_1 in some address. Why?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm using the [Place Autocomplete Address Form](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) to retrieve the information about the address.

It works fine, but in some address, the `sublocality_level_1` is not being returned.

**Address 1:** Rua Barão de Ipanema - Copacabana, Rio de Janeiro - State of Rio de Janeiro, Brazil

- Street: Rua Barão de Ipanema (addressType: route)
- Neighborhood: Copacabana (addressType: sublocality_level_1)
- City: Rio de Janeiro (addressType: administrative_area_level_2)
- State: State of Rio de Janeiro (addressType: administrative_area_level_1)
- Country: Brazil (addressType: country)

**Address 2:** Rua Clarimundo de Melo - Piedade, Rio de Janeiro - State of Rio de Janeiro, Brazil

- Street: Rua Clarimundo de Melo (addressType: route)
- Neighborhood: Piedade (**missing sublocality_level_1 addressType**)
- City: Rio de Janeiro (addressType: administrative_area_level_2)
- State: State of Rio de Janeiro (addressType: administrative_area_level_1)
- Country: Brazil (addressType: country)

In Rio de Janeiro, "Copacabana" and "Piedade" are neighborhoods. Is the same type of information.

We have other examples:

- Av. Vieira Souto - Ipanema, Rio de Janeiro - State of Rio de Janeiro, Brazil (Returns correctly the sublocality_level_1 - Ipanema)
- Estrada Adhemar Bebiano - Del Castilho, Rio de Janeiro - State of Rio de Janeiro, Brazil (DO NOT Returns the sublocality_level_1 - Del Castilho)

"Copacabana", "Piedade", "Ipanema" and "Del Castilho" are neighborhoods.

But, if I insert the STREET NUMBER, the `sublocality_level_1` is returned. See the example: Rua Clarimundo de Melo, 460 - Piedade, Rio de Janeiro - State of Rio de Janeiro, Brazil

All of these tests were done on the Google Places API example page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

I insert the address and using the Google Chrome Inspector, I see the returned values.

**2 other curious things:**

- The formatted address is: `formatted_address: "Rua Clarimundo de Melo, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, Brazil"` - Different the value in the address input field
- The query string in the url is different the address input field: `url: "https://maps.google.com/?q=Rua+Clarimundo+de+Melo,+Rio+de+Janeiro+-+RJ,+Brazil&ftid=0x997d3beb826455:0xbe0de6bc2d7d1c22"`

I don't know why 4 address, with the same structure, has different returns.

Someone knows why? I appreciate any help.

## EDIT 1 - THE STRONG SUSPECT

**Multiple Neighborhoods**

Something is in my head now. "Rua Clarimundo de Melo" and "Estrada Adhemar Bebiano" crosses some neighborhoods.

"Rua Barão de Ipanema" and "Av. Vieira Souto" crosses only one neighborhood.

I tested with 2 other streets:

- "Avenida Ataulfo de Paiva - Leblon, Rio de Janeiro - State of Rio de Janeiro, Brazil" - Cross only the Leblon (neighborhood) and returns the `sublocality_level_1`
- "Avenida Atlântica - Leme, Rio de Janeiro - State of Rio de Janeiro, Brazil" - Cross 2 neighborhoods (Leme and Copacabana) and DON'T return the `sublocality_level_1`.

This is a suspicion because is not documented in any place. That's why it's just a suspicion. A strong suspicion, but a suspicion.

If my suspicion is correct, why does not returns the neighborhood if the user manually inserted the neighborhood in the input?

This is not clear. The user types the neighborhood...

**Reverse Geocode**

I'm testing the address in the [Geocoder Tools](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/). The `sublocality_level_1` is not returned yet. BUT, if I put the coordinates in the [Reverse Geocode](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/), *vòila*, the `sublocality_level_1` is returned.

Perhaps, this is a solution, but I don't know if is a correct solution. Because I will need to do 2 requests to Google Places API to get the locality info and the requests has a month limit. 2 requests creates a lack of efficiency.

- Request 1: Get the address info.
- Request 2: If has no `sublocality_level_1`, use the reverese geocode to get the complete address info.

Comment: Downvote without comment. Classy

Comment: Your assumptions seem really logical. If you have a result of type route and this route crosses several neighborhoods, it is likely that service won't return anything. I've seen similar things with postal codes and routes that cross several postal codes. The reverse geocoding might be the only solution in this case. When you add house number and get rooftop results there is no doubt to which neighborhood these rooftop addresses belong.

Comment: @xomena Unfortunately, reverse geocoding isn't 100% correct. I'm testing the address: "Av. Atlântica, Leme, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, Brazil". The neighborhood is "LEME". The coordinates are "-22.966552,-43.176324". Reversing Geocode, the `sublocality_level_1` returned is "Copacabana", which is a neighborhood very close (side by side neighborhoods). In other words, not working, because the real neighborhood for the typed address is "Leme".

Comment: I don't know why Google doesn't return the correct neighborhood, if I'm typing the neighborhood AND Google shows the neighborhood name in the auto-complete predictions box. I'm click in the prediction with the neighborhood name! It's crazy!